# Firefox add-on that will count number of clicks at listed urls

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to write Firefox add-on that will follow users activity for chosen web links at some webpage. Because I'm not so familiar with web development, I would appreciate your suggestions and directions how to finish this task.

I already made one simple Firefox add-on, but yet don't have idea how to mark wanted links and how to make counter for clicks at that (chosen) links. Probably I need to add function in JavaScript file that will be placed in content folder and called within html file, but I need your help how to locate wondered web link? I.e. do I need to locate it using Element ID (and how to do it) or there is some other way?

Also, if somebody knows similar add-on that is already written, that would be perfect!

Thanks in advance!

Nemanja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you just need an event listener listening for the `click` event. You could call `content.document.addEventListener('click', myListener, true);` every time a page loads, or you could just call `gBrowser.addEventListener('click', myListener, true);` when the whole program starts up. Either way, `myListener` will be passed the click event as an argument, so then you can do something like:

```
function myListener(event) {
  if (event.target.href && event.target.href === 'some.url.com')
    updateCounter();
}
```

I hope this makes sense.